# How to use parts of the old URL in a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

is it possible to keep certain parts of an URL and to rewrite the rest? With a .htaccess 301 redirect.

In my example I would like to rewrite URLs from this format

```
http://blog.example.com/post-name
```

to this one

```
http://example.com/2014/post-name
```

So far the year (2014) can be static because only a couple of links would be affected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that this'll redirect every request to `blog.example.com` since it's just capturing anything after the slash and redirecting, so please clarify if you need it to be smarter, but..

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/2014/$1
```

Comment: To clarify for anyone else: I pointed the .blog subdomain to an empty folder in which I put a .htaccess file with the above line. Works perfectly. Thanks.